# How to restore default XFCE theme ("Adwaita-Manjaro-Dark") in Manjaro?

Tags: xfce, theme

I recently installed Manjaro Linux, and today I started trying out new themes.
I [read](http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.de/2013/09/manjaro-087-ascella-xfce-review-superb.html) that the default theme for Manjaro XFCE is called ["Adwaita-Manjaro-Dark"](https://github.com/manjaro/artwork-adwaita-manjaro-themes/tree/master/Adwaita-Manjaro-dark).

But for some weird reason this theme does not show up in the list in the "Appearance" dialog.
And now I can't get back to the original look.

Any ideas?

(I can provide more info if I know what to look for)

Answer (score 2):

You should try installing adwaita-manjaro-themes in octopi, or alternatively run

```
sudo pacman -S adwaita-manjaro-themes
```

in a terminal.
Either of these should install the adwaita themes for XFCE.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. I reformatted your answer to make the command easier to read, and rephrased it to be more a (potential) answer than looking like a comment asking for more information (which could get the answer closed). Even if you are not 100% sure this solves the OPs issue, you should present it as an answer, the voting and acceptance mechanism of the site will finally determine its appropriateness.

Comment: Well.. I switched back to Mint about a week ago, and no longer have a Manjaro system to test this. So I can't really "accept" the answer. But still a +1 for the effort.